# Symmetric lax monoidal functor takes operads to operads

Tags: reference-request, functors, monoidal-categories, operads

I am looking for a reference to the following theorem.

> If $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ is a symmetric lax monoidal functor between symmetric monoidal categories, then it induces a well-defined functor $\underline{F}:\mathrm{Op}_\mathcal{C}\to \mathrm{Op}_\mathcal{D}$ between the categories of operads.

I believe this is a well known fact and I have my own proof of it, but my supervisor suggested me to find a reference instead of writing my own proof if it is already in the literature.

However, I haven't been able to find it so far. I couldn't find it in Loday and Valette's  *Algebraic Operads* nor in Yau's *Colored Operads*. I also asked some other mathematicians and they didn't know about a reference for this, even though they agree it is well known.

Can anyone give me a reference for the above result?

Comment: It's exactly the kind of thing I expect that nobody ever wrote down because it's "too obvious" for expert, and too advanced for textbooks. I hope you find something, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in Fresse's book *Homotopy of Operads and Grothendieck-Teichmüller Groups*, volume I, Proposition 3.1.1(a).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will use that one! I don't completely agree with the autor when he says that the partial composition maps "*clearly* satisfy the equivariance, unit and associativity relations of operad" tho, it is intuitive but it took me a while checking them at it was not so trivial.

Comment: @Javi How is it nontrivial? Just write down the commutative diagrams...